# Should this question be migrated?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I posted a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96255/are-these-terms-considered-uncivilized-to-native-english-speakers) which got closed as not constructive. The reason, as [a user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) has pointed out, being

> but your link to that acceptability of touristic question isn't really relevant to what we're talking about here. In general, I think questions of the form "How offensive is [some term which is know to be at least potentially offensive]" are Not Constructive. Everyone has an opinion, but none of them can be "right" or "wrong".

Which I do not deny *partly*. I got two requests here:

1. Travel.SE might be a site where these type of questions may be asked (as I get to [see some of the examples](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=polite)). So maybe this question should be migrated there. I request so because it has got 1 delete vote already here.
2. If I am unable to quote these terms (*used in the question and marked as offensive as several users*), how can I come to know *usage* of these terms in some cases (*This question might not be the last to force me to use them*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe Travel.SE would be an appropriate location for this question. Accordingly, I do not intend to migrate the question unless a Travel.SE mod indicates to the contrary.

As to your second question, [existing site policy](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive) is that offensive words **may** be used if those words are the subject of discussion. As far as I can tell, the question has not been flagged as *offensive*, so I'm not sure where you got that idea from.

Comment: Actually several comments from different users, an [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96259/31053)  also a delete vote made me to think so!

Comment: @Mistu4u: If you didn't consider your example words at least *potentially* offensive, why "sanitise" them with asterisks in the first place? I don't see any comments suggesting that anyone took offence at the fact of you alluding to profanities (some of which which several people just wrote out in full anyway). There's one *answer* saying your usage was offensive - but that's mainly attracted downvotes, and in any case the poster makes it quite clear in his second paragraph that he's being ironic rather than condemnatory. The down/closevotes aren't relevant to "offensiveness".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Actually the down-voted answer was the 1st answer to the question, so I thought maybe the community would consider it offensive. So I put asterisk. If you advise, I can `rollback`. But I apprehend few users may still find them offensive!

Comment: @Mistu4u: I don't understand your position at all. No-one except you seems concerned about the fact that in order to *discuss* offensive words, we sometimes need to actually *write* them. Even ipso's semi-facetious answer was downvoted by people who don't want there to be any suggestion that we here at ELU might be "shockable". I downvoted the question because I thought it was tiresome, not because it was offensive. The only unexplained downvote is one for Bill Franke's answer, for reasons I cannot even guess at.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Okay thanks for clearing the confusion! I am relieved now!

Comment: @Mistu4u: I'll probably get more flak for calling your question "tiresome" than you will for asking it. But - as I'm sure you realise - "acceptability" on ELU is very different to what would be considered reasonable in other contexts (the workplace, college, or just public space in general).